# Which heroes can jungle, even in special circumstances?

Tags: dota-2

I know that there are a category of heroes that are [junglers](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Category:Junglers) and can do it very well, but as I was learning one of the newly released heroes ([Medusa](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Medusa)), I discovered that under specific circumstances, she can jungle the ancients group as soon as the game starts.

This is done by chopping down some specific trees with the quelling blade, and using an observer ward to grant vision.  (example videos: [#1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLuq7hyBXh8), [#2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFjvHg1woPw)).

What other heroes not listed as a jungler can jungle using very specific items or tactics?

Comment: I'm not sure how well this question can be answered. In theory, practically any hero *can* jungle, it's mostly a matter of determining how well they actually succeed at doing so. How are you going to measure that here?

Comment: @FAE well, jungling effectively means you aren't blowing all your initial gold on potions and running back to the fountain to heal.  You have to be able to get a reasonable amount of gold and keep pace with other lane heros level wise

Comment: That dota2wiki list is not very good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unconvention jungling been done in various ways with:

- Luna, who can jungle with early glaives and abusing aggro resets - [YouTube Guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xpDLRShttY)
- Medusa, who can kill Radiant ancients with split shot - [YouTube Guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9NoHaYnCShM)
- Tinker, who can kill ancients with March - [YouTube Guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzlCAtZoE7g)
- Invoker, who can kill Radiant ancients (and Sunstrike!) with an Exort build - [YouTube Guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rpv_8tcUSm4)

The problem with all of these heroes is that it's very easy to shut them down and steal their farm, and it's very conspicuous as none of the heroes are viable roamers or gankers early in the game. Jungling usually means doing so from level 1 and keeping pace somewhere between a dual laner and a solo in terms of experience.

To be complete, the following heroes can jungle (traditionally) reasonably well:

- Axe
- Batrider
- Chen
- Doom
- Dark Seer
- Enchantress
- Enigma
- Legion Commander
- Lifestealer
- Lone Druid
- Lycanthrope
- Nature's Prophet
- Ursa

The following heroes can jungle if it's absolutely needed but they're slow at doing so and thus probably shouldn't:

- Bloodseeker
- Crystal Maiden
- Huskar
- Phantom Lancer
- Sand King
- Shadow Demon
- Wraith King
- Troll Warlord

Comment: add jugger + qop + kotl to the crappy junglers list?

Comment: KotL can't really do it until level 2 because he's out of mana after 2 nukes. Ditto Juggernaut and QoP, they need to courier so much regen that it's not even close to worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are many heroes that can jungling at the start of the game.

1. **Ursa**
   Ursa is the best jungler. He can solo roshan at early game, he can kill ancient creep at lv.1.
2. **Lifestealer**
   He has lifesteal at level 1. He can jungling vere well. He can kill ancient creep at lv.1 too.
3. **Enigma**
   He can change enemy creep into eilodron under his control. He can double his eilodrons in 6 attacks. He is best jungler.
4. **Chen**
   Best support and jungler. He has 4 Helm of Dominator. He can dominate ancient creep too. I promise he cant be killed by neutral creep at lv 1 when Chen is jungling.
5. **Nature Prophets**
   He has an abillity that can change trees into treants. He is God of Jungle. He can get many gold in a minute.
6. **Alchemist**
   He is the fastest farmer hero ever. He can get Radiance in 15 minute only. He can solo ancient creep with his skill 1.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, junglers like Nature's Prophetand Lycan can be very much help with ganking. They can roam while their spawns are active and can be good at being first in every neutral creeping.Nature's teleport/ult and Lycan's ult are suprisingly good combination of surprise ganks and intimidation to enemy heroes. If you want a jungle that not only farm and gank, but also become a late game initiator, try Barathrum. His charge and ult is the best initiator in teamfights because he can zone out the most fed up heroes with no escape abilities such as Sniper, Tinker, Lanaya, and other Intelligence-type heroes that you can engage.