# How do I Jungle with Nature's Prophet?

Tags: dota-2

I have not been playing DOTA 2 for that long, and have only really been laning and playing standard. But I would love to start to jungle - the only problem is, I am not sure how to do this in a proper way. Well - I know the basics.

I want to learn to play as a jungler using Nature's Prophet.
There might not be a guide "This is how to win by Jungling with NP" - but I would love to know how to be effective.

**How do I effectively jungle with Natures Prophet?**

*(If you believe there's a better alternative of hero choice, I would love to know which one, and why.)*

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3tjIyA4oTo

Comment: Also, a list of viable junglers: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/103327/11047

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pretty much any hero in the game can benefit from jungle in order to free a lane (with creep stacking and pulling :
[See Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KFFu-Q4X9mM)). There are several characters that can do it without the creeps, Nature's Prophet is one of them and you can start practicing with him. There are several starting items you can get with different benefits:

- 4 or 5 *Clarity Potion*: will help you sustain and summon more treants
- A *Gloves of Haste* + 2 *Clarity Potion*: for a *Hand of Midas* rush. However your low mana pool and high manacost of summon will force you to go back to base a few time
- Ring of Basilius + 2 x *Clarity Potion* (My favourite) : it will make your treants stronger, give you a pretty good early mana regen and give you a damage aura for you and your treant
- *Null Talisman* + *Clarity Potions* (not recommended) : Use this start ONLY if you want to have some fun with the ganking teleport Nature's Prophet and rush a *Dagon*. Thus the *Null Talisman* will be used for the *Dagon*.

Now the strat for an efficient start: Treants last for 60sec and have a 37sec cooldown (which means you can have 2 packs summoned at time). The first spawn of neutrals is 30 sec after creep spawn (00:30 gameclock). So for an efficient start you will want to summon treants 7 second before the game starts at the fountain (free mana regen). By doing this you make sure that the cooldown of 37sec will be up at 00:30 (when neutrals spawn) allowing you to get 2 pack of treant for starting. Kill a small camp, (you have about 25 second) > step away and let the camp respawn (at 1:00) > kill it again. You are now level 2 and you can start trying to kill either a big camp (avoid Hellbear Smasher before level 2 treants) or keep going with small/medium. It is really (really) important to micro your treants to not let them die, make them run away when they are low life so neutrals will change target, then put them back in the fight. You will gain a lot of damage thanks to this. You can even sometime let neutral target you instead of your treant to get more damage. I advise you get an early (at level 2) point in Teleport so you can fountain trip faster if needed.

I advise no matter what your starters items are, to rush a *Hand of Midas* and use it every time it's off cooldown on a big neutral from a big camp (you get x2.5 XP and this will help you boost your XPM (experience per minute)). I am not going to expand on how to play Nature's Prophet and what item build you should go for but *Hand of Midas* will help you farm faster any item you would need for you and your team  (*Power Treads*, *Shadow Blade*, *Mekansm*, *Scythe of Vyse* etc.)

**Some tips to keep in mind**

- Being in the jungle does not mean ignoring the lane. You have one of the most powerful early game ability : Teleportation. You can turn any situation by teleporting in and giving your team a +1 advantage. If you get several kills you can even transition your gank into a tower push.
- Watch out for the enemy courier (especially in early game). If you spot it try to teleport on his way back and snipe it. If you manage to do that while the enemy mid is bottle crowing, it can ruin his early game but remember to...
- ...always keep a TP scroll on yourself. If you use Teleportation agressivley, the TP scroll will allow you to come back to base as soon as you're done.
- You can use Teleportation while invisible with *Shadow Blade* / *Shadow Amulet* / *Silver Edge* and it won't break the invisibility
- Try to get at least 1 escape mechanism (*Force Staff*, *Blink Dagger* or *Shadow Blade* so you can use Teleportation safely)
- When teleporting to a lane to push, don't TP directly in the lane but TP in the trees instead, then if the lane is safe clear your path by creating treants, it'll be much safer.

If you want to jungle with someone (like N'aix) who doesn't summon units, you migh want to check this video about [Choke Point Jungling](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQUmVctbSUQ)

Comment: I use the: A glove of haste + 2 clarity potions and if you play it correctly, for example the 7 seconds before the game starts treant summon and the tanking the neutrals yourself, you can easily stay in the jungle without going back to base(maybe once).

Answer (score 11):

WizLiz made a pretty good description of what to buy, how to launch your spells and how to kill monsters. But being in the jungle with Nature's Prophet is **more** than juste killing creeps.

Remember than this hero got one of the most powerfull Dota 2 skill : **Teleportation**. Which means that he basically can go everywhere in a few seconds. That is what makes him such a good Jungler or an even better off-lane hero.

With a typical jungler you will usually kills creeps until you are ready to get out of the jungle. With Furion, don't forget that your role is also to help your mates killing on their lanes. At level 5 you should have 1/1/3, to be able to teleport on a lane, kill a hero (using sprout if necessary) and TP back to base (don't forget to always carry a TP with Furion, this is true with all heroes but with his teleportation you may forget that this is a life saver).

If you want to be a good jungler with Nature's Prophet, **observation** of the whole map and **communication** (if possible) are essential. If you see your team-mates ganking, and if you think a teleport would help the job, or that you can finish a fleeing hero by teleporting on his path, do it. That is what makes Furion so powerful, even during the first 10 minutes of a game.

Remember : **don't get stuck** in your jungle, that would be a huge waste with Nature's Prophet.

Edit : Would have been better as a comment of the previous answer, but I can't comment yet.

Edit 2 : You also must use teleportation in a defensive manner. If your offlane is being chassed under his tower, a TP + sprout can completely change the outcome. I suggest to watch some replays, especially with [AdmiralBulldog](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/AdmiralBulldog), who is part of Alliance and the best Nature's Prophet player in the pro gaming community.

Comment: Fully agree with this, this is the MOST IMPORTANT part of jungling.
Too often you will see a prophet who just sits in the jungle for 20 minutes while your team has to play 4v5, and if you lose the laning stages 4v5 you will most often lose the game entirely as the enemy team snowballs out of control.
Since there is not much to look at in the jungle, you can spend all your time looking for kill opportunities in other areas of the map.